# Best solution for automated testing in a multiple application scenario

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests, testcomplete

I'm trying to choose automated UI testing tools for the following scenario, with 4 applications:

- app 1 one application with a WEB UI
- app 2 one flex application
- app 3 one html5 application
- app 4 one application with a WPF UI

So, ideally, I'm looking for a all-in-one solution. Something that can handle the tests for both WEB (apps 1, 2 and 3) and WPF (app 4), like SilkTest, TestComplete and Seapine QA Wizard.

However, app 4 will soon disappear, and the need for testing it will too. Leaving me with only WEB UI applications. In that scenario I'd go with Selenium, no question here.

So,

Question 1: Would you recommend the all-in-one solution, even knowing that in the future it'll only be used to test WEB applications? If so, what tool do you think it's best?

Question 2: If I choose to go with Selenium for the web apps, I still need something to test the WPF one. I'm looking at Project White. Would it be the best tool for the job, or should I look at something else?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're setting yourself up for *alot* for pain if you try and find a one-fits-all-solution for this sort of problem.

You should definitely use Selenium to cover off the web stuff. I've yet to see an automated testing framework that's more functional or easier to pick up than Selenium (and it's various subprojects). That's the right solution for the web apps.

A particular consideration is that if you're making the automation investment for the long term, you don't want to saddle yourself with a sub-standard tool just because it supports web and WPF apps. Given that you'll eventually be getting rid of the WPF app, make that testing requirement secondary for now. Over the long term, the majority of your effort will go to testing the products, so use the best tool for that (in my opinion, Selenium).

As for the WPF app, there are probably some fairly decent tools available (I recall an HP rep saying that they were looking at getting WPF test automation into their enterprise testing suite).

Bottom line, you're looking at two very different sets of needs so finding a common test tool will be difficult. Use the best solution for each job and save yourself headaches down the line.

Comment: I agree with everything you said. I realize that nothing comes close to Selenium in web testing, nevertheless I tried to find a not-so-bad tool that I could also use for my WPF project, and I find it quite impossible to find such tool.

Question 2 still needs answering though, as I haven't found a tool that handles WPF as well as Selenium handles web.

Comment: I agree with @Peter - if the WPF app is going away soon, then any investment in automation for that app will likely be wasted. And Selenium is definitely awesome. However, if the WPF app were to stay around, I would encourage you to explore the one-fits-all solution. The commercial products (IBM, HP, MSFT, others) all do a good job with both web and desktop apps. If you need to support web + desktop apps, you are generally better off in learning one tool (All-in-one) rather than two (Selenium+Desktop).

Answer (score 1):

One advantage of an all-in-one solution is that there is only one learning curve for all technologies. You mentioned that app 4 (using WPF) will go away soon, but you may want to determine if other technologies will be used by your company in the future.

QA Wizard has worked well for me. The status tool allows me to remotely monitor results. QA Wizard also offers load testing and stress testing functionality which makes it a powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

I think a Gherkin-based language such as Cucumber or Specflow would be really helpful here. I'm assuming that most of the functionality should work similarly across each platform, so you should be able to write a single set of scenarios describing the behaviour at a sufficiently high-level, and then implement different step definitions for each platform, e.g.

- Selenium for the web or HTML 5 versions
- [wipflash](http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/) for WPF
- [FunFX](http://funfx.rubyforge.org/) for Flex

Comment: I like your ideia, but your assumption is wrong. In this case all the apps have their own behavior. I wouldn't save that much time and effort by using that solution.